# How can I complete the failed upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade to 12.04 LTS but it got stuck at 36 minutes to complete upgrading. I restarted the computer and cannot boot my previous version of Ubuntu 2.6.32.

It stuck at this message:

```
since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may also use the start (8) utility..
```

Comment: The message you showed us is no error message. We will need more info, but first: how long did you wait after this message appeared?

Comment: Hi, there were some more messages with [OK] at the end. I waited for about 15 minutes but nothing happened